# Location Selector giving me null for position(coordinates of place I marked to set location)

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, position

So basically I have this application where i try to add an event and specify the location of the event through map selector in which I will mark the location through google maps.However, I need that input of coordinates if the marker I set for location and I dont know how to get it. Any help?

Here's my code for opening the map selector:

```
     RaisedButton(
                            onPressed:() => Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new ActivityMapSelector())),
                            child: Text('Location')
                        ),
```

Here's the code where I try and extract that marked location:

```
 void _submit() {
    if(formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      formKey.currentState.save();
         Geoflutterfire geo = Geoflutterfire(); //USED GEOFLUTTERFIRE
    var pos = ActivityMapSelectorState.marker.position;
   GeoFirePoint point = geo.point(latitude: pos.latitude, longitude: pos.longitude);
      DateTime finishDate = selectedDate;
      finishDate = new DateTime(selectedDate.year, selectedDate.month, selectedDate.day, selectedTime.hour + int.parse(_activityDuration), selectedTime.minute);
      selectedDate = new DateTime(selectedDate.year, selectedDate.month, selectedDate.day, selectedTime.hour, selectedTime.minute);
      Firestore.instance.collection('avtivity').document().setData({'category': "activity",
      'latlng': point.data, // HERE'S WHERE I TRY TO GET THE DATA AS GEOPOINT
        'dateAdded': DateTime.now(), 'description' : _activityDescription,
         'title' : _activityTitle,
        'type': _activityType, 'date': selectedDate, 'city': _activityCity, 'dateFinish': finishDate});
      Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new PlaceTrackerApp()));
    }
  }
}
```

Any way to fix this?

Comment: you probably need this, 'point.geoPoint' Returns a Firestore GeoPoint, not 'point.data'

Comment: are you passing in  the coordinates from any Google Maps API like Geocoding API?